# consultar si una tabla esta bloqueada en oracle desde php

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-11g, php5

consultar si una tabla esta bloqueada en oracle desde php

Estoy intentando hacer una consulta a una tabla oracle con php, buscando saber si la tabla esta bloqueada o no.

- Si esta bloqueada continua con el proceso y guardo el id del proceso en una tabla.
- Si no esta bloqueada ejecuto un procedimiento.

Intente hacer lo siguiente para probar en ambiente de desarrollo:

> Bloquear una tabla a proposito

```
LOCK TABLE CLIENTES IN EXCLUSIVE MODE
```

> Verificar si tabla esta bloqueada

```
SELECT *
FROM CLIENTES 
FOR UPDATE NOWAIT;
```

Como tengo una respuesta en oracle si una tabla esta bloqueada o no?

Comment: Puedes hacer una consulta a [`V$LOCKED_OBJECT`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/dynviews_2028.htm#REFRN30125), por ejemplo: `SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM V$LOCKED_OBJECT l INNER JOIN DBA_OBJECTS d ON l.object_id = d.object_id WHERE d.object_type = 'TABLE' AND d.object_name = 'CLIENTES';` luego verificas si `total` es mayor que `0`, en cuyo caso la tabla `CLIENTES` estaría bloqueada. En el `WHERE` se pueden poner más filtros, por ejemplo, si quieres saber si la tabla está bloqueada para un usuario en específico, etc.

Comment: @A.Cedano Hay alguna forma de bloquear una tabla a proposito para probar la consulta que me pasas. pruebo con LOCK TABLE CLIENTES IN EXCLUSIVE MODE pero no bloquea la tabla

Comment: Recomiendo que leas la [documentación sobre `LOCK TABLE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9015.htm),  dice por ejemplo esto: *Una tabla bloqueada permanece bloqueada hasta que confirme su transacción (`commit`) o la deshaga, ya sea completamente o en un punto de salvaguarda antes de bloquear la tabla.* O sea, para que la tabla se bloquee tiene que estarse operando sobre ella, insertando, actualizando, borrando.

Comment: @A.Cedano me funciona para detectar los bloqueos .Gracias! como podria detectar si un registro en especifico esta bloqueado?